# If else statement connected to substring use leads to else-statement only whatever the user input

Tags: c++, if-statement

When I compile the code, it always leads to the last else statement for unknown reason for me. I am running out of time so rapid help would come in handy. I promise to research just after I file my assignment in eCourse.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    string K; 
    cout << "Sisestage isikukood:\n "; 
    getline(cin, K);
                  /* Küsin kasutajalt isikukoodi*/
    std::string(str2) = K.substr (1,1);  
    std::string(str3) = K.substr (2,2);  
    std::string(str4) = K.substr (4,2); 
    std::string(str5) = K.substr (6,2);  
    std::string(str6) = K.substr (8,2);
    cout << "Isikukoodi I andmed:\n ";

    if (str2 == "1") 
    {                  
        cout << " *mees\n"; 
    } 
    else if (str2 == "2") 
    {                  
        cout << " *naine\n"; 
    } 
    else if (str2 == "3") 
    {                  
        cout << " *mees\n";
    } 
    else if (str2 == "4") 
    {                  
        cout << " *naine\n"; 
    } 
    else if (str2 == "5") 
    {                  
        cout << " *mees\n"; 
    } 
    else if (str2 == "6") 
    {   
        cout << " *naine\n";           
    } 

    if (str2 == "2" || str2 == "1") 
    {                  
         cout << "* sundis " << str3 << "." << str4 << "." << "18" << str5; 
    }
    else if (str2 == "3" || str2 == "4") 
    {                  
         cout << "* sundis " << str3 << "." << str4 << "." << "19" << str5; 
    }
    else if (str2== "5" || str2 == "6") 
    {                  
        cout << "* sundis " << str3 << "." << str4 << "." << "20" << str5; 
    }

    if (str6 == "00") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Kuressaare Haigla\n"; /* Leian haigla, kus on isikukoodi omanik sundinud */
    }  
    else if (str6== "02") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Ida-Tallinna Keskhaigla, Hiiumaa, Keila, Rapla haigla\n";
    }     
    else if (str6 == "22") 
    {                  
        cout << " *  Ida-Viru Keskhaigla\n";
    }  
    else if (str6 == "27") 
    {                  
        cout << " *  Maarjamõisa Kliinikum,Jõgeva Haigla \n";
    }  
    else if (str6 == "37") 
    {                  
        cout << " *  Narva  Haigla \n";
    }     
    else if (str6 == "42") 
    {                  
        cout << " *  Pärnu Haigla \n";
    }    
    else if (str6 == "47") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Pelgulinna Sünnitusmaja , Haapsalu haigla \n";
    }              
    else if (str6 == "49") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Järvamaa haigla \n";
    }  
    else if (str6 == "52") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Rakvere, Tapa haigla \n"; 
    } 
    else if (str6 == "57") 
    {                  
        cout<<" * Valga haigla \n"; 
    } 
    else if  (str6 == "60") 
    {                  
        cout << " * Viljandi haigla \n"; 
    }
    else if  (str6 == "65") 
    {                  
        cout<<" *  Lõuna-Eesti Haigla (Võru), Põlva Haigla \n"; 
    }                       
    else
    {
        /*Tulemus,kui isikukood on sisestatud valesti*/ 
        cout << " Sisestasite isikukoodi " << K << " .Palun proovige uuesti.\n";  
    }  
    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It must be that none of the conditions evaluate to true.

Comment: So *first* you want to file your assignment, and *then* to understand it?

Comment: I am in 10 minutes time, so I think I will not forget my mistakes to learn from them, but if your judgement stands I can understand it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. When I give it "0233445522", it does not execute the last `else` statement.

Comment: You won't learn anything in 10 minutes time, especially if you ask others to do it for you. Btw since this is an international forum, posting your program written in English would not be a bad idea, so even people who are not from Estonia would manage to understand what your program is trying to do, even if you provide no description of it.

Comment: I am sorry, the way I behaved was truly arrogant and inappropriate.As I said I had 10 minutes until the deadline and I was ready to put in time to research my mistakes right after submitting my assignements.I would not have posted an Estonian code to international forums otherwise nor request you,stackoveflowers, to do anything like this if it hadnt been my last desperate move. I had enough time planned for the assignements but I fell ill for 4 days, where I had high-temperature with muscle pains so I was bedisck the whole time. I truly am sorry for this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
  static std::map<std::string, std::string>  message1 = /* Initialize once */;
  static std::map<std::string, std::string>  message2 = /* Initialize once */;

  cout << message1[str2] << "\n";
  cout << message2[str2 + ":" + str6] << "\n";
```

Comment: Do not quite understand how to implement it , is there a page for it on cplusplus.com as I did quick search on it and did not find it.